# How to send a message from a client to a server using Qt WebSockets

Tags: c++, qt, qt-signals, qtwebsockets

I am using the webclient and webserver from the Qt examples

echoclient.cpp - https://pastebin.com/z8bgfQzE
client main.cpp - https://pastebin.com/g1DtjjYa

echoserver.cpp - https://pastebin.com/V7aqHu2L
server main.cpp - https://pastebin.com/Ni7CAXKu

And I have a simple `Send` SLOT:

```cpp
void EchoClient::Send() {
    QTextStream qtin(stdin);
    QString word;
    qtin >> word;
    int sBytes = m_webSocket.sendTextMessage(word);
    std::cout << "Send bytes: " << sBytes << std::endl;
}
```

I want to enter data all the time, but I don't know what I can bind as a signal to trigger the slot:

```cpp
connect(???, ???, this, &EchoClient::Send);
```

I tried overriding the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key press, but I couldn't do it in a Qt console application.

Comment: You are not giving enough details for us to understand how a word is supposed to be sent. Besides, it could have been useful to edit your other question on that same topic to make it more understandable.

Comment: @Atmo Tell me what information is needed, I will provide it. It seems to me that there is no point in posting .cpp and .h files that do not particularly affect this function

Comment: I seldom use `QTextStream` so there is a little chance I am wrong but it seems it waits for your input in the console and will get a word every time you press <kdb>Enter</kbd>. The reason why you can't find a signal to connect your slot to is because you could just call `Send()` in a loop in your `main` and that would send messages typed in the console line by line. It is likely you want, instead, **NOT** to read the in stream in `Send` but instead declare it as `EchoClient::Send(const QString&)`, and have something else read the input and emit signals.

Comment: @Atmo Initially, I wanted to call the `Send` method in the main program loop, but since I want to constantly send text, it is necessary to have an endless loop, which disrupts the operation of the entire QT application, and nothing is processed. As I understand it, `return a.exec()` processes all events and functions in the loop, but if I create my own, then the QT cycle simply doesn’t get to the turn

Comment: That is exactly why I said you did not give enough details.... What exactly is your application supposed to do?

Comment: @Atmo I added more details in the question, if you need anything else tell me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the events from the main loop to be processed between each time a word is read, you need to make use of connections. This can be achieved with only 1 class but I suggest you limit the responsibilities of `EchoClient` so that it only does the communication. Something else will read from the input stream.

Correct `Send` so that it only sends words it receives:

```cpp
void EchoClient::Send(const QString& word) {
    int sBytes = m_webSocket.sendTextMessage(word);
    std::cerr << "Send bytes: " << sBytes << std::endl;
}
```

Another class is in charge of reading from the input stream. We want it to read one 1, let the main loop process events, then be prepared to read the next word, and so on.
It results very roughly in:

```cpp
class KeyboardReader : public QObject {
Q_OBJECT
public:
    KeyboardReader() {
        //Connection to make KeyboardReader::readWord loop upon itself by the event loop
        QObject::connect(this, &KeyboardReader::start, this, &KeyboardReader::readWord,
                         Qt::QueuedConnection | Qt::SingleShotConnection);
    }
signals:
   void start();
   void wordReceived(const QString& word);
public slots:
   void readWord();
};

void KeyboardReader::readWord() {
    QTextStream qtin(stdin);
    QString word;
    qtin >> word;
    emit wordReceived(word);
}
```

Then, the `main` function should look similar to:

```
int main() {
    QCoreApplication a;
    EchoClient client;
    //Initialize/connect client here

    KeyboardReader reader;
    //Connection to make the message read by reader propagate to client
    QObject::connect(&reader, &KeyboardReader::wordReceived, &client, &EchoClient::Send);
    //Connection to make KeyboardReader::readWord loop upon itself in the Qt main loop
    QObject::connect(&reader, &KeyboardReader::wordReceived, &reader, &KeyboardReader::readWord);
    
    emit reader.start();

    return a.exec();
}
```